Stuck as a solo dev
I'm 22 years old, and I work as a solo, full-stack developer for an education company. When I was 15, I sold them a small project which simply did some royalty calculations. I did a few on-and-off projects including through my college years (16-18, graduated with AA), and they hired me at 19 to try (knowing it might not work out) and build a replacement for our old Moodle LMS website which had been running for over a decade.
This was actually pretty successful. I built a new LMS, an importer for Moodle backups (lots of nastiness there - my favorite was an element type which stored data as a class, stringified the class, base64-encoded the string, then threw that into an XML file, for seemingly no reason). We migrated hundreds of courses with their staff, people are exceedingly positive about it, there's plenty of a future there.
However, now that I've almost finished the hardest work... I'm kind of racked with self-doubt. I've never worked on a professional development team - even once. My stack of choice is primarily Laravel, Livewire, Alpine, and Tailwind; which worked beautifully (my boss has said that I really, really sold my design skills short when I said I wasn't a designer), but isn't a particularly common or desirable setup elsewhere.
As such, I'm just... afraid and a bit ridden with imposter syndrome. Can I claim to be a front-end developer if I don't know React or Vue? Can I claim to be a back-end developer if I don't know Go or Java? And despite my best attempts to follow good practices (S3 storage! Return types!), do I even really know how to develop at all?
That's where I feel stuck. I just want to build the best product I can, and not stagnate. I just don't know what to do next.

Yes, you are a developer.
You designed something.
You built it
You sold it.
You maintained it.
You are a million miles ahead of most of the people calling themselves developers.
Focus on your long-term - or at least short-term - career growth.
Where do you want to go from here?
Don't start filling yourself with imposter syndrome. Nobody knows everything. Pick an area that seems interesting to learn AND there is demand.
You are humble enough to know that you don't know everything. That is important because it allows you to grow quickly. The "I know everything" people are hard-headed are a pain to work with.
Security is always important to include in any learning path.
Good Luck

True-- You are a million miles ahead of most of the people calling themselves developers.

And you will find that fluency in one language or set of tools speeds up learning others, since at least some of the concepts will be similar enough to move across. It does require being able to learn the idioms of the new tools, and recognize when old solutions aren't as good a fit, but that comes with practice. Don't get hung up on front end versus back end developer; the ideal is to be able to move fairly smoothly from one to the other, and that too comes with practice.

I recently worked with an "I know everything" developer who was self taught and had been confidently calling everyone else idiots for 15 years before I was hired as the second developer, and the best developer I've worked with in the last 20 years was hired as the third. "I know everything" was literally the worst developer I've ever worked with (an intermediate at best level developer who wanted to "teach" experts to do things exactly like him). He is no longer working with us.

Very good encouragement, but I would also add to find what you are passionate about and start making your personal goals about that.  The place you work for is not who you are.


Can I claim to be a front-end developer if I don't know React or Vue?

Of course. Do you think everyone using Angular or Ember isn't a front-end developer either?

Can I claim to be a back-end developer if I don't know Go or Java?

Of course. Do you think everyone using C# or Python isn't a back-end developer either?
OK, I took those questions literally :)... You are a developer, you just use a different tech stack.
If you think that what you are using is too much of a niche, then spend some time to learn something more in demand. Do a bit of research and see what that might be and which one you like better. Then go from there.
And keep in mind that what you choose won't be something you retire with. Things change. Everything changes. I started with C#, then moved to Java, then back to C#, then did some Python for a few things before moving to Java + C#. On the front-end I mostly used plain vanilla Javascript and various specific frameworks before using Angular (and hating it) then React (and loving it). And now I don't do any of those things because I moved onto other roles.
Build a learning plan, try to follow it. Inspect and adapt.

And despite my best attempts to follow good practices (S3 storage! Return types!), do I even really know how to develop at all?

This is a bit more complicated of a question, with a more complicated answer. It's fine to be a solo developer if you know there might be things you don't know and if you question that one solution might not be the best choice. It seems you have that awareness already, which is good. But this means more things to learn by yourself.
In a team, you can bounce ideas around, you can look at how others aproach things, you can get advice, you can have company best practices laid out for you to follow, there is peer reviews, you could find a mentor, etc. As a solo developer you don't have this "support structure" in place. You have online communities for most of the topics, but that will be up to you to follow up solo. You need to make a plan for how to incorporate these kinds of things into your work, just like you incorporate new technologies.
To give you an example, many years ago, what really was a turning point for me - I would saying from moving to being a programmer to being a software developer - was reading Fowler's book Refactoring. Start there :)
As closing words I would say: you are young, you have time. It will be easy to get overwhelmed and frustrated and stressed about chasing all the things you think are important. Take things one day at a time and you will get better.

"If you think that what you are using is too much of a niche, then spend some time to learn something more in demand." - There's some value in updating the existing software to something that can more easily be maintained by others. If you think React is what you should learn because it's what everyone else uses, you could migrate (parts of) what you have now to React.

If you've been working on this for several years and it works and it provides value to the business then it's a legit project. The point of business software is to make money for the company, not to be a jewel of technical finesse. (Solid technical structure is part of long-term profitability, but the goal is profit, not being on the new shiny framework.)
What you've done is a lot more than someone just coming out of uni has probably done. You learn valuable things in uni, but there are also things you can't learn in uni. One of the most important things is working on a project for more than a year. Uni projects are almost all single-semester proof of concept things. You don't have to really worry about long term maintainability or stakeholders wanting new features later on. You already have that experience and it's something businesses really care about. I would say in job interviews, the single most important thing to communicate is that you've worked for multiple years on valuable software products.
Also, the Laravel ecosystem is absolutely a valid one. It's one where businesses achieve their goals and make money. I don't want to get into a tribal war with other ecosystems, and I don't have to. I'm sure they're fine too. Laravel is valid because it allows businesses to ship quickly and earn money, and keep doing it for years.

So, it's not justified to feel like an impostor, because you're delivering too much real value to be one.
But you're right to be thinking about where to go from here. I've worked as a solo dev in a company, developing their internal product. At some point I hit a ceiling what I could learn there. I left to be a TA for a year and then joined an agency serving multiple clients. I now have colleagues to learn from, and with multiple clients also came more varied challenges. It's been a good shift for me.
I would say, don't run away from where you are right now. But it's time to start looking around for the next thing. You have a stable job, so you have the time to look around carefully for something that's really good for you.
In your shoes I'd be trying to find something roughly like this:

A bit further out of my comfort zone than my current job, but not completely in the danger zone. It needs to be challenging but I do need to be able to see that I could learn to do it well, and see real progress within a couple of months.
Right now having good colleagues and a good boss are really important, because you wanna get experience as a team dev. You want a company with a healthy development process and smart people you can learn from.
You want to be pretty open about what you can and can't do. It's normal that people don't already know all of the technologies at a new job, because real businesses all have somewhat different tech stacks with that weird thing we do at this company. Now knowing their particular email sending framework is not a dealbreaker for example. They're not hiring someone who knows everything; they're hiring someone who's smart enough to learn any specific thing they need learned. But to get a good start at the job, it's good to get in the open what you already know and what you still need to learn, so that everyone's expectations are aligned. (And if they have difficulty with that, that's a warning to you that this might not be a good company for you.)


You can claim to be a full-stack developer; you are one.
For the back end: yes, some more technical people use crazy language X, Y, or Z, but PHP/Laravel is a legitimate choice. Most programmers don't know every language. The concepts and expertise in creating a successful API are more important than the language. Learning some new syntax is not such a big deal.
If you have hacked a livewire/alpine frontend to work, it means you have a deep understanding of front-end JS. React has its own quirks/paradigms, but they mostly make the process easier, not harder. Excellent React developers know how websites worked before React. You have a very successful main project, which can be a kind of tunnel vision; consider adding some hobby projects to play with React or something else.
The team of one thing is probably your biggest shortcoming; collaborating with other developers is definitely a technical and soft skill that takes practice. One way to mitigate that skill lack would be to think of how you work with yourself. Try using Git and pull requests successfully, especially using a popular platform like GitHub or GitLab. Try using collaborative task management software like JIRA or ClickUp if you are not already; get a habit of documenting the process. Finally, and this is kind of a hard thing to get started with, consider contributing to an open-source project.
For some general life advice, it is much harder to get a formal education or a new specialty as you get older and have more obligations, such as rent or a family to support. This successful project is a great experience but can also be "golden handcuffs", or something that becomes too profitable to quit even if not your dream. Unless you want to be a solo web developer for life, be careful!

Agree with the thing about learning collaboration skills. If you didn't learn git yet.  Definitely try committing your own code changes, and look out for other skills/tools which you might be tempted to not bother with as a solo developer. Linting tools. Test frameworks. etc.  It's a mistake I made actually, working a solo dev for years and skipping a few of these niceties. Eventually other developers joined the team, and my code didn't make a good first impression.

Yeah, the important thing about being a "frontend" or "backend" developer is that you understand the concerns relevant to frontend or backend development -- and by extension, a "full stack" developer is someone can productively work on both as-needed. In either case, familiarity with specific tools and frameworks is a separate conversation.

"React has its own quirks/paradigms, but they mostly make the process easier, not harder"
This feels like the intent... but rarely the outcome with React codebases!

@RobPotter sounds like a mismatch of paradigm and personality quirks

One possible future path is for you to explore the option of founding your own software company.
You are young and very talented. So, you could go very far with founding you own company to create a new and exciting software product.
You don't have to quit your current job right away. You can keep your current job, and at the same thing thinking about a new software product. Once you find an idea for new software you like, on your free time (outside the company time) at home, you can even start the design and coding phase for the new product (while still working at the current company for your day job).

Visionary engineers and business men such as Bill Gates, Steve Jobs, Elon Musk, etc ... don't want to spend their whole life working for the MAN who tells them what to do and could lay them off at any time. These visionary talents want to found their own company to maximize their creativity and productivity.
Even "normally talented" engineers and business men, who could found their own companies, would enjoy that option. Their business still can be very successful.

"Visionary engineers and business men such as Bill Gates, Steve Jobs, Elon Musk, etc ... don't want to spend their whole life working for the MAN who tells them what to do and could lay them off at any time. These visionary talents want to found their own company to maximize their creativity and productivity.
Even "normally talented" engineers and business men, who could found their own companies, would enjoy that option. Their business still can be very successful."
Big ditto on this.  I'm a "normally talented" developer who's built an almost 40-year career working pretty much exclusively in an environment considered by most as obscure (TurboPascal/Delphi) which included a 13-year stretch at my own software company.  Building a successful company from scratch can be stressful and exhausting, but it can also be incredibly satisfying.  These days, I'm just a couple years from retirement and much happier without that stress working for someone else.  But over that long career, I've never been out of work for more than 3 weeks, so here's a data point for the notion that working in "obscure" or "less popular" tools should not be automatically written off as an unmarketable skillset.

I'd only like to add that you also made something that solves the clients problems, that they are genuinely happy with. And you implemented it in their organisation.
So when thinking about you future you could opt for a product owner role or something similar, if you find that more interesting then development.

Claiming to be a certain marketing buzzword title like "full stack"/"front end" etc isn't really meaningful. You can specialize in certain areas for sure, but it's all just different flavors of technology. Imposter syndrome is about caring more about how fancy your professional title sounds than about the actual work you are doing.
So don't worry too much about learning particular programming languages, technologies or platforms/libraries. The longer you work, the quicker you'll pick up things like that and notice that in the end, the differences aren't that significant, when looking at the big picture and the end result. Also, learning technologies is something you can simply do alone by studying and it's not necessarily something you need live human input about (though taking classes is always nice as one learns quicker that way).
What truly makes a good developer are mostly technology-independent skills like how to do program design, preparing for testing, production and maintenance in advance, problem solving & troubleshooting skills (major one!), how you organize the work and the projects etc. Essentially the whole development cycle which eventually ends up in support and maintenance. Most of this you can ultimately only truly learn from practical experience and that is where input from those already having that experience is extremely valuable.
Regardless of skill and experience, you might find it interesting to simply get input from others regarding how to solve a problem. As someone who has worked a lot alone or on small teams, I know that one might easily get stuck with one solution to a problem which does solve it, but it might not be the optimal way. Maybe the way you do it is time consuming or error-prone. Fine-turning the professionalism and discipline in your development cycle is how you make higher quality products with less bugs, that are easy to maintain. To get there, we often need input from others. So it might be nice to join a larger organization just for that.
However, be aware that the down side of joining a larger organization is that you'll get flooded with lots of distractions that aren't actually related to the core work, which is product development with the purpose of delivering a useful end product to a customer. Things like project management, version control, deployment, people/team skills etc are all good, but they aren't the core product. In larger companies, people tend to obsesses too much about the tools and forgetting that the most important part is always what those tools are used for.
Now of course, some might find it more interesting to work as a "tool sharpener" than a developer, so by trying new things you might find something else you enjoy working with other than development - who knows. A lot of engineering degrees focus on turning you into a developer, but many enjoy working with technology even when their role isn't product development.
Being in your twenties means it's the best time in your career to try out new things, before settling down. Later on in your career you might have a house and/or family etc etc and therefore appreciate steady employment and short commuting more, and be less flexible about moving around. Though as of today, we still don't quite know where the whole remote work trend will land, of course.

'marketing buzzword title like "full stack"/"front end" etc isn't really meaningful' - I wouldn't completely devalue these terms. I actually used to think the same as you expressed here, but when I started working with people who were explicitly described as "front-end developers" and they had to visit the other layers of the application from time to time nonetheless, I realized just how big the gap to having "full-stack expertise" (vague a term as it may be) actually is.

@O.R.Mapper It's all experience of various areas of programming, which is a much wider and complex scope than "front end"/"back end". There is not a single programmer out there who knows everything. ->

Personally I've dabbled a little bit with a lot of things, and when writing GUI I soon started to realize that the hardest part was how to make everything look good and remain user-friendly at the same time, which aren't even programming topics, that's the job of a graphic designer. Or on the other extreme end, embedded systems where you are so close to the hardware that you also leave the realm of programming and enter electronics. And everywhere - knowledge of the core purpose of the application you are making, which could require literally any skill not related to programming whatsoever.

Join a mid-sized or larger company who is known to have software as part of their product. Become a team player, learn thing you never needed as a solo programmer.
Then you can decide to start your own company, join a startup, or climb up the  corporate ladder.

Someone who has worked successfully as a solo developer tends to not fit in with a large software development group. It would be better just to talk to those developers over beer and learn what they do.

"Change jobs" is a pretty extreme piece of advice for somebody that, from all indications, has found a job where the employer and employee are mutually satisfied.

I don't think this answer makes a great case for it, but changing jobs is actually quite reasonable advice for someone who wants to get exposed to new technologies and practices and broaden their experience. (i.e. career growth) Especially if they don't see a path to doing so within their current company. If the employer and employee are mutually satisfied, that's great, but it doesn't mean that working relationship has to continue forever. (And it sounds like the employee is not entirely satisfied in this case.)

Agree with @DavidZ here; I don't understand the downvotes.
Sure you could have beers with people who tell you how they do things, or you could work with them and learn from code reviews, feedback on tech designs etc...
The "learn thing you never needed as a solo programmer." is particularly relevant in my opinion. I think the honest answer to the OP's question is not a pat on the back saying "you're great", it's saying that working solo is great to learn many things, and working in a team is great to learn others things. Do both to learn both.

If you know any one (or more) sever scripting languages and at least one (or more) database then you are a back-end developer.
With client side it's different. There are people who think jQuery is JavaScript, it is not, it's "like" JavaScript but it's own thing. So if you know HTML/XML, CSS and real JavaScript (not dependent on frameworks or libraries) then you're a front end developer. You can know some extra stuff so long as it's on top of the basics for being a front-end developer.
You're looking at yourself as a static string instead of a dynamic variable. Will you fit in just any team? No, no one person is that capable though you're far ahead of most people at 22 especially for programming. Any place that expects you to know 100% of what they're already doing is run by crackheads. Any place that refuses to teach you how they do things to get you up to speed is run by crackheads. Any place run by crackheads is run by crackheads.
The most difficult part of going from a solo developer to a developer team is learning something like Git to merge code and learning programming policies. From what I've seen the vast majority of places have zero concern over quality (in the grand scheme of things) and will just use what is conveniently within perception. So just be sure to spruce up on a language you don't know when get a serious response for a job application and take notes religiously until you're solid on your own.

There are people who think all back end frameworks are the same, They're not. There are people who think all databases are the same. They're not. Picking a front end library that's been obsolete for about 10 years to use as a comparison for javascript seems strange.

@PlayerOne jQuery is still incredibly popular. While it's no longer needed in its capacity as a compatibility shim, and I'd personally like to put it to rest, it's still pretty useful. Debouncing is one example. Most modern web frameworks are obsolete when they come out, being mere fads; but jQuery earned its popularity.

@wizzwizz4 sure, but I'd challenge you to find one serious front end developer in 2024 who thinks jQuery is the same as Javascript.

@wizzwizz4 Unless you are saying that you think that jQuery is the same thing as Javascript then I'm not sure what you think you proved there.

@PlayerOne A lot of people call the browser's built-in DOM APIs "pure JavaScript". We don't often say that they're wrong, even though they're not mentioned in the ECMA-262 specification, and Node.JS is a perfectly-conformant JavaScript implementation that doesn't feature them. jQuery has just as valid a claim to be considered JavaScript as many of the browser's built-in DOM APIs – or arguably more, since it predates many of them. Saying "jQuery isn't JavaScript" is a kind of useless pedantry: better to say "jQuery is unnecessarily heavy" or otherwise describe its actual problems.

@wizzwizz4 I didn't say JQuery isn't a Javascript library, I said they aren't the same thing. i.e. they aren't interchangeable terms. The example front end developer in the second paragraph of the post that we're commenting on would claim that they are. I asserted that no serious front end developer in 2024 would make that mistake. I'm not sure what you're trying to argue, but it seems to be a completely different point.

In some contexts, they are interchangeable terms. In general, they're not, but in general no two words are interchangeable (not even the closest synonyms). Most people who assert things like "no serious X would do/think Y" (e.g. me, eight years ago) aren't competent to assess ability: they're mainly assessing "cultural fit" instead. This answer doesn't hide that it's about "fitting in" (and the writing style doesn't try to disguise the answer's flippant perspective, making it imo valuable despite the dubious advice), but not everyone is aware that they're looking at a proxy metric.

@wizzwizz4 "React is a jQuery library, as is Angular" is not a meaningful sentence. Words do actually mean things and can't be interchanged at will. I guess if you genuinely do believe that then I'm wrong, and the strawman developer in the post really does exist.

@PlayerOne Let us continue this discussion in chat.
